# How does COM connection point work internally from a server (component) DLL to client EXE

Tags: c++11, com, atl

I recently going through some code in my project and found that the server DLL has implemented an interface IConnectionPointContainerImpl.
I want to know how it works internally to callback a method of client (EXE) from server (COM component) DLL.
How does COM connection point work to make a callback internally from a server DLL to client EXE.

Comment: ATL comes with full source code. You can read it, or trace into it under debugger. At the end of the day, the client hands to the server an interface pointer to a COM object (called "event sink"), by way of `IConnectionPoint::Advise`, which the server stores for later. To "fire an event", the server simply calls a method on that interface.